# Visual Studio hangs when adding forms or opening designer

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2019, designer

I have a major problem with a Winforms application with a large number of projects.  VS 2019 threw an exception and closed a few days ago, and on reopening restored two files since then I have been unable to:

1. Add a new form to the vast majority of projects, whether the most basic MS template or not
2. Open the designer for any form that is already in the vast majority of projects
3. Access the navigation bars (the three combo boxes at the top of the VS work area that normally contain the project, namespace and content information) on any class referencing to WinForms in the vast majority of projects

When trying to do either of the first two things an 'Opening File' message is shown endlessly.  If you try to do anything, a notification is shown that Visual Studio is busy, and that Microsoft will be notified but nothing else happens and you can only get out by using the Task Manager to kill all VS tasks.

In the case of the third one, a message is shown saying 'Refreshing Navigation Bars' but again it goes on forever.  However, in  this case you can click the Cancel button to cancel the loading attempt.

The navigation bars issue I believe is Resharper related.  In addition CodeLens is not working at all, so the space for the number of references is generated but there is no content.  This is true for ALL files in the solution, not just the form related ones.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- Cleaned and Rebuilt the solution - works fine but no difference
- Built and deployed the solution - works fine
- Deleted the SUO file and reset
- Cleared the Resharper caches
- Disabled Resharper
- Performed a repair install of Visual Studio
- Created a new Solution and added forms etc. which was unaffected and worked fine
- Opened a different solution which was also working fine
- Tried the same processes with a Project in the same solution that is not part of the application (TestBed) and that works fine too, but is the only project that does

Can anyone suggest where to look now?  Since new and existing solutions work OK except for this one I am assuming that it is something Solution related rather than something related to VS itself, but I have no idea what that might be.  For example, what is it trying to do when it says 'Opening File' (apart from the obvious - opening a file :-)) and what could cause that to fail?  Am I looking for something in the Solution file, or could it be something else?

All suggestions and assistance towards resolving this issue would be gratefully received.

Comment: What do you mean by "vast majority" in your three introductory bullet points? Are you saying that some projects in the same solution have the issue cited in the bullet while others do not? Also, which 2 files did VS 2019 recover when you reopened the IDE after it had shut itself down?

Comment: As stated in the question, I have at least one project called TestBed which is part of the solution but not part of the application.  This is a mature application with 139 projects just in the main application and several million LOC, so I have not checked every single file in every single project but I have tested enough to know that the vast majority had the issue.

Comment: You're welcome. Just letting you know that when you wrote "large number of projects", I expected maybe 15--not 139. Your definition of large and mine apparently differ. Now it's more clear why you would use the phrase "vast majority". It would have been nice to have the exact numbers early on just to get a sense of actual rather than perceived size. In any event, Step 6 in your answer is what intrigues me the most. Let's hope that checking Output and Errors (always a good idea) is the step that is most useful to others should they experience something similar.

Comment: Hi @Jazimov, as I said in my answer none of the errors mentioned in step 6 could possibly have been related. Whilst I was waiting for suggestions here I continued development rather than sit and wait for responses :-)  As I said in the question I had already built and deployed so there were no errors at that point but I included the step for completeness stating the issues were unrelated.  The removal and installation of a different version of VS was something I decided to try in desperation since I still had the necessary licenses available, and frankly I was very surprised when it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jasimov for the only response, I appreciate your attempt to help.

I have now resolved the issue using the following steps:

1. Uninstall Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition
2. Perform a fresh install of Visual Studio 2019 Professional
3. Reload the main solution
4. Clean the solution
5. Rebuild the solution
6. Deal with some issues that were highlighted in the Output and Errors, none of which were directly forms related
7. Rebuild the solution
8. Run the application and ensure it runs as expected
9. Go back and select forms at random and try opening them.  All now work as expected.

In addition CodeLens is now working not only properly but actually better than before giving more information more quickly.  On the other hand, I have not yet reinstalled Resharper which will be the next step.

I have included all the steps I took just in case anyone else has a similar problem. I have not been able to find this exact issue anywhere else in my searches so I hope it helps someone.

**UPDATE:** I have since re-installed Resharper with no problems and the designers are all working fine so now back into full flow!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the **web** forms designer in VS2019 hanging as soon as I clicked on anything on the design surface. The same projects were OK in VS2017. Uninstalled VS2019, rebooted, reinstalled VS2019, found that the designer was now working OK. Progressively added back 3rd party toolbox components, one VSIX, and the .Net 4.8 targeting pack. Still working. Thanks for your hint about the reinstall.

Comment: Are you politely saying thanks? Or would you say that you posted a new separate answer which provides an additional insight?

Comment: Original intent was primarily to say thanks, though I wasn't 100% certain we were solving the same problem. Unfortunately I'd failed to spot that the original post related to winforms rather than webforms. So it wasn't the same problem, just the same remedy.

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](/help/why-vote).